# Macbook Pro, BenQ GW2765HT, and Displayport cable

Tags: macbook-pro, thunderbolt, displayport

After a few days to a week of normal use of my MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015 with Intel Iris Graphics 6100 1536 MB) and the BenQ GW2765HT LED monitor via display port, I found that my mac was no longer being detected by my monitor and vice versa. I had no idea what to think except that the wire I had was faulty, so I exchanged it for one of the same brand. And then, bam, another week or so into use of the new wire the same thing happened. This time I decided to exchange it for another brand of Mini Displayport to Displayport cable. The same thing again! Clearly I was not taking the right approach to this problem.

My usual “setup/workflow” is that I have my monitor closed and use only the external display. At night, I turn off the monitor and unplug the power to my MBP (to not overcharge my battery) in no particular order. I wonder if my pulling the power, or some combinations of actions is killing the cable? Any thoughts?

[This was my original thinking, but I have just gotten the cable working again—will offer a preliminary solution below.]

Answer (score 1):

I disabled the ddc/ci on my monitor and, while my HDMI cable was connected at the same time, swapped to DisplayPort and the cable started working again somewhat magically.

I'm really not sure what happened, but I'm chalking it up to the ddc/ci thing.

Comment: That seemed to work for me too.  This was driving my nuts.  This would happen from time to time and magically fix it's self.  I also tried the DP v.1.1.  I can't say which fixed it but it's worth a shot.